# Is rounding behavior of string-to-double methods defined?

Tags: .net, floating-point, floating-point-conversion

Ideally, a string-to-double method would always yield the `double` whose value was closest to the exact numerical value of the specified string; for example, since "102030405060708072.99" is only 7.01 away from the next larger value, but 8.99 away from the next smaller value, it should round to the next higher value.  Neither `Convert.ToDouble` nor `String.Parse` seems to work that way, however; both cause that value to be rounded down.

It appears that the behavior is to ignore everything past the eighteenth digit, even if values beyond that cold affect how things are rounded.  Is there anything that *specifies* such behavior?  Is there anything that specifies that every decimal representation of 18 digits or fewer will always be mapped to `double` value which is no more than half an LSB away from the precise represented value, notwithstanding the fact that numbers of 18 digits or more may be mapped to a value which is nearly 9/16 of an LSB away from the indicated value?

Based upon [Why is a round-trip conversion via a string not safe for a double?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24299692/why-is-a-round-trip-conversion-via-a-string-not-safe-for-a-double) it would appear that the behavior of conversion routines may vary between platforms.  To what extent is such behavior a deviation from spec, and to what extent does the spec leave such behaviors open?  Is there anything in any specification which would indicate that adding a `0` to the end of the fractional part of a formatted `double` will not affect the result of parsing?

My own expectation would be that floating-point methods should specify the degree of accuracy they promise.  In the absence of any specification to the contrary, I would expect floating-point methods to yield a result which would be within 1/2lsb of the arithmetically-precise result that would be yielded with some combination of numeric operands that were within 1/2lsb of the values passed, since that level of accuracy can often be achieved for about the same cost as anything sloppier, but accuracy beyond that is often much more expensive.  If a method is going to take extra time to achieve better accuracy, it should specify that (to encourage code that needs to be fast, but doesn't need the full precision, to consider a faster n alternative).  Code should not require for correctness that a method it uses be more accurate than that unless the method promises better accuracy.

The `R` formatting option for `double` values in .NET is supposed to yield a value which, when parsed, will match the original operand, but does not specify what method of parsing should be used to achieve that result.  If one wants to convert floating-point values to strings in such a way as to guarantee system-independent round-trip-ability, what must one do to ensure that any legitimate implementation of a parsing method will parse it the same way?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if C# supports it, but the standard technique (as in, it's in both the C 99 and later standards, and the IEEE-754 2008 floating point standard) is to use [hex float format](http://www.exploringbinary.com/hexadecimal-floating-point-constants/), which can represent a float exactly without any rounding.

Comment: Certainly hex float format has a lot of advantages, but there is something to be said for having "human-readable" numbers that are also machine readable.  Decimal format is bulkier, but it should still capable of uniquely representing a given `double` value if the behavior of the parsing method is specified.

Comment: Yes, it is possible and other libraries (e.g. glibc) can do it. However it requires some careful programming: see http://www.exploringbinary.com/how-glibc-strtod-works/