# Round Trip Conversion in Java

Tags: java, double

I was going through:

[Why is a round-trip conversion via a string not safe for a double?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24299692/why-is-a-round-trip-conversion-via-a-string-not-safe-for-a-double?newsletter=1&nlcode=296994%7c0f21)

and just wanted to see what happens such situations in Java.

```
public class RounfTripConversion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Double d1 = 0.84551240822557006;
        String s = d1.toString(); // String("r");
        Double d2 = Double.parseDouble(s);
        System.out.println("Double 1:" + d1);
        System.out.println("Double 2:" + d2);
        boolean equal = d1 == d2;
        System.out.println("Double 1 and 2 are EQUAL is " + equal);
        System.out.println("Double 1 - Double 2=" + (d1 - d2));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> ```
> Double 1:0.8455124082255701
> Double 2:0.8455124082255701
> Double 1 and 2 are EQUAL is false
> Double 1 - Double 2=0.0
> ```

Can someone help me understand why a boolean comparison that returns both `d1` and `d2` are not identical, although that's the case?

Answer (score 2):

Because Double is a class so d1 and d2 point to different objects:

```
Double d1 = 0.84551240822557006;
String s = d1.toString();
Double d2 = Double.parseDouble(s);

boolean equal = d1 == d2; << FALSE
```

But the value of the double stored in the Double will return true when compared:

```
boolean equal = d1.doubleValue() == d2.doubleValue(); << TRUE
```

What confuses you i think is the difference between **double** and **Double**. Where double is a primitive type, just the value, and Double is a wrapper class that contains the value.

What happens here is **autoboxing**. You write the following:

```
Double d1 = 0.84551240822557006;
```

But what really happens is:

```
Double d1 = new Double(0.84551240822557006);
```

So you have a reference to a **Double** class that contains a **double**.

If you would do:

```
double d1 = 0.84551240822557006;
```

Then you would have just the value and not a reference to a class that contains the value.

Comment: Found this is the RELEVANT answer for the question.

Answer (score 0):

Both the  Double values are identical but not pointing to the same reference.

Look at   [`compare()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#compare%28double,%20double%29) method in `Double` class.

Comment: Yes, but wouldn't it auto-unbox the two values prior to comparison?

Comment: Nope, won't auto-unbox unless you cast one of them to primitive double.

Comment: While true, you still need an epsilon to compare the actual values of the `Double` to see if it is truly equal.

Comment: @staticx can you please refer to compare method ?

Answer (score -1):

While in this case, suresh has a point about it doing an object comparison, even using two `double`s would give you false.

Floating point numbers (`float` and `double`) are [stored as a mathematical expression](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).  Converting a `double` to a `String` will truncate it.  So, the new double after converting it back will not have the same value as the original.

Answer (score -1):

When comparing floating point numbers, in this case a `double` boxed into a `Double`, you need to take care to use an epsilon to compare the actual values. The reasons are detailed in this [excellent article by Bruce Dawson](http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm).

What you really want is something more akin to `isNearlyEqual`. People expect equal to be transitive. At the very least, you need to convey the idea that it is no longer transitive.

To that end, you shouldn't do exact comparisons. From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8081911/2591612):

```
double a = 1.000001;
double b = 0.000001;
double c = a-b;
if (Math.abs(c-1.0) <= 0.000001) {...}
```

In your case, you are comparing the references to two `Double`, which doesn't compare the actual value.

Comment: You make it more complicated then it is, my answer was absolutely correct, simpler to understand and given 10 minutes earlier.

Comment: -1 to @fonZ and 1+ to staticx. fonZ your answer is absolutely wrong. Floating point equality is never absolute, and staticx "over complications" are in fact necessary.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels ok, tell me exactly what is wrong instead of downvoting without explaination?

Comment: @fonZ: I already stated why. Floating point equality is never absolute, and staticx "over complications" are in fact necessary.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels that is totally off topic, the op is asking why his comparison doesnt return true.

Comment: In this particular case, the API promises exact value equality, so there is no need for an epsilon to check whether it is working.

Comment: @Patricia: if using .equals, but OP is using == instead. .equals uses doubleToLongbits