# How can I create a unique hashcode for a JObject?

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm trying to implement a cache for `JObjects`.

I was surprised to see that they didn't override the `GetHashCode` method and therefore, I can't use it as a unique key.

Since my json's are pretty large, I don't want to use `JObject.ToString().GetHashCode` as a solution.

I did see that they have an internal method called `GetDeepHashCode` but the implementation is based on other protected properties and therefore, I cannot "copy" the code and create an extension method from it.

I also don't want to use reflection and invoke the internal `GetDeepHashCode` method.

I'm looking for a way to create a unique cache key for a `JObject` and I don't want the method to be extra expensive when it comes to performance.

Comment: Are you sure that you want to use GetHashCode as a unique key? According to the definition different objects don't need to have different hash codes

Comment: Are you expecting the hash codes to be the same after a round-trip to and from a string representation?  Because a `JValue` can contain a `double`, and doubles [do not round-trip without precision loss](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24299692/why-is-a-round-trip-conversion-via-a-string-not-safe-for-a-double).

Comment: @HaraldCoppoolse - I understand that and I understand that when you have collisions the Equals method is invoked. That's the reason that you need to override Equals when you override GetHashCode.
Since they didn't override GetHashCode, I'm looking for a fast way to do that.

Comment: @dbc - I'm trying to avoid the round trip to and from string. I don't care if I lose some cache hit's on specific occasions.

Comment: What I mean is, if you round-trip a `JValue` containing a double from and to JSON, its hash code may change.  Anyway, use [`JTokenEqualityComparer`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JTokenEqualityComparer.htm), it does what you need.

Comment: @dbc - I understood you comment regarding the double and the class was exactly what I was looking for. The GetHashCode method excepts a JToken as a parameter. Please post this as an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`JTokenEqualityComparer.GetHashCode(JToken token)`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JTokenEqualityComparer_GetHashCode.htm) for this purpose.  It provides access to the `GetDeepHashCode()` method you saw.

```
var obj = JToken.Parse(jsonString);
var comparer = new JTokenEqualityComparer();
var hashCode = comparer.GetHashCode(obj);
```

Note that [`JTokenEqualityComparer.Equals(JToken x, JToken y)`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JTokenEqualityComparer_Equals.htm) calls [`JToken.DeepEquals()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_DeepEquals.htm) ([source](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JTokenEqualityComparer.cs)) so this comparer is suited for use as an [`IEqualityComparer<JToken>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx) when constructing hash tables or dictionaries of LINQ-to-JSON objects and uniqueness of values is desired.