# Filtering out the set difference of two List<JObject> in C# using LINQ

Tags: c#, arrays, json, linq, json.net

I have 2 `List<JObject>` to be compared for their set differences,

The format of the two `List<JObject>` to be compared are as follows:

**This is the JSON structure for my base `List<JObject>` :**

```
[
    {
        "name": "competency",
        "subLists": [
            {
                "canonicalForm": "c1",
                "list": [
                    "c one",
                    "c 1",
                    "cone",
                    "Cone"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "roles": []
    },
    {
        "name": "demoList",
        "subLists": [],
        "roles": []
    }
]
```

---

**This is the JSON structure of the `List<JObject>` that I want to find the set difference against:**

```
[
    {
        "name": "competency",
        "subLists": [
            {
                "canonicalForm": "c1",
                "list": [
                    "c one",
                    "c 1",
                    "cone",
                    "Cone",
                    "C ONE"
                ]
            },
            {
                "canonicalForm": "c2",
                "list": [
                    "c two",
                    "c 2"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "roles": []
    },
    {
        "name": "leavetype",
        "subLists": [
            {
                "canonicalForm": "annual",
                "list": [
                    "Easter"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "roles": []
    },
    {
        "name": "demoList",
        "subLists": [],
        "roles": []
    }
]
```

---

**With the output set difference JSON being:**

```
[
    {
        "name": "competency",
        "subLists": [
            {
                "canonicalForm": "c1",
                "list": [
                    "c one",
                    "c 1",
                    "cone",
                    "Cone",
                    "C ONE"
                ]
            },
            {
                "canonicalForm": "c2",
                "list": [
                    "c two",
                    "c 2"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "roles": []
    },
    {
        "name": "leavetype",
        "subLists": [
            {
                "canonicalForm": "annual",
                "list": [
                    "Easter"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "roles": []
    }
]
```

---

**I have tried using the following code using two for-loops:**

```
List<JObject> baseList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JObject>>(baseListString);
List<JObject> comparedList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JObject>>(comparedListString);

List<JObject> finalResultList = new List<JObject>();


for (int i = 0; i < baseList.Count; i++)
{
     for (int j = 0; i < comparedList.Count; j++)
     {
        if(baseList[i]["subLists"] != comparedList[j]["subLists"])
                        finalResultList.Add(comparedList[j]);
     }
}
```

But this is not cutting it, I want to compare the entire `JObject` based on the key values of `name`, `canonicalForm`, `list` keys and filter out the set difference using LINQ. But I am unable to do so.

I have tried using `.Except()` extension method but that is not working as well.

---

**Edit:**

I want to check if there is any change in the 3 keys which are: `name`, `canonicalForm` and `list`, if there are any change in the compareObject compared to the BaseObject I want to return the JObject which has the change. The output is displayed above.

---

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you deserialize json to a concrete class instead of JObject?

Comment: I don't want to deserialize it into concrete class for requirements. Can't we  not directly apply LINQ?

Comment: Could you use [`JTokenEqualityComparer`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JTokenEqualityComparer.htm)?  See e.g. [How can I create a unique hashcode for a JObject?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39507631/3744182).

Comment: @dbc in this context I want to do that based on 3 keys: `name`, `canonicalForm` and `list`

Comment: `Except` will not work and `baseList[i]["subLists"] != comparedList[j]["subLists"]` will not work either. They will not work because simply comparing one list to another (`!=`) is not what you are after. You need to state the rules of what equality and difference mean in your case. Then write the code for those rules. We do not know the rules because you have not told us.

Comment: @CodingYoshi I have reworded the question

Comment: Also don't even use Linq or real code to begin with. First try your solution with pseudocode and do a walkthrough, do you get the desired result? No, keep working on your pseudocode. Once you get the desired result, time to write simple c# loops and then test that. Does it work? No, keep modifying your code. It finally works, then ask "would this look and read better with Linq"? Yes, time to convert loops to Linq. No, you are done.

Comment: @CodingYoshi how do you propose to compare inner `JObject(s)` for equality?

Comment: Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42708070/how-do-i-create-a-dto-in-c-sharp-asp-net-from-a-fairly-complex-json-response) answer to create actual classes and override their `Equals` method. It will be little code you write for each class and how they compare and thus it will be easier. Write the code for every class which needs comparison. Then you can use `Equals` in your loop and see if they equal eachother. This will take time so just relax and go one step at a time. Spend more time thinking and less programming.

Comment: @KunalMukherjee Typically, in the field of programming, we accomplish tasks of that (or any) nature by using existing code if possible (in this case it clearly is not), or else by writing our own code.

Comment: @EdPlunkett But there is no existing library for comparing the equality of two `JObjects` that's why I am forced to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: @KunalMukherjee If that wheel doesn't yet exist, you're not re-inventing it. You're just programming, which very often entails writing code.

Comment: @EdPlunkett in this case I think I may have to use 4 loops to check their equality, is there some efficient way?

Comment: Does `Enumerable.SequenceEqual()` match for nested properties?

Comment: You could write your own method to compare sequences (it would have only one loop in it, not four of them). That would be very good practice and I recommend it. You could also use [`Enumerable.SequenceEqual()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342073(v=vs.110).aspx), which behaves exactly as documented with regard to nested properties.

Comment: Can we override `Enumerable.SequenceEqual()`? for writing our custom logic?

Comment: @KunalMukherjee You can't override a static method. What you can do is use the version I linked with the `IEqualityComparer<TSource>` parameter, and write an equality comparer class which implements `IEqualityComparer<TSource>` and compares the nested properties appropropriately. To minimize confusion in all of this, I urge you to take Yoshi's advice and write a C# class to deserialize to. Trying to do it all with `JObject` will magnify the difficulty of every step in the process. And it's difficult enough already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I finally solved my problem by implementing the `IEqualityComparer` for `JObject`.**

---

Here is my `JObjectEqualityComparer` class:

```
public class JObjectEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<JObject>
    {
        public bool Equals(JObject x, JObject y)
        {
            if (x == null && y == null)
                return true;
            if ((x != null && y == null) || (x == null && y != null))
                return false;

            return JObject.DeepEquals(x, y);
        }

        public int GetHashCode(JObject obj)
        {
            JTokenEqualityComparer comparer = new JTokenEqualityComparer();
            int hashCode = comparer.GetHashCode(obj);
            return hashCode;
        }
    }
```

---

**Finally I have used this overload of `.Except()` extension method to find the Set Difference.**

[image]

---

**Here is the code:**

```
List<JObject> baseList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JObject>>(baseListString);
List<JObject> comparedList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JObject>>(comparedListString);

List<JObject> finalResultList = new List<JObject>();

finalResultList = comparedList.Except(baseList, new JObjectEqualityComparer()).ToList();
```

---

Thanks to [Ed Plunkett](https://stackoverflow.com/users/424129/ed-plunkett), [dbc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3744182/dbc) and [Coding Yoshi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4228458/codingyoshi) for pointing me out in the correct direction.